# JPARepository findAllByUsername return null but data exist

Tags: sql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a simple System ( Controller, Service, Repository ) but even if the data are present on the database the service returns a null value

Data

```
mysql> select * from customer;
+----+---------------+
| id | username      |
+----+---------------+
|  4 | liparistudios |
+----+---------------+
```

Domain

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 201811031445L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE )
    private Long id;

    private String username;
```

Controller

```
Customer c = customerService.searchCustomerByUsername( usernameToFind );
```

Service

```
@Service
public class CustomerService {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepo repo;

    public Customer searchCustomerByUsername( String username ) {
        return repo.findAllByUsername( username );
    }
```

Repository

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface CustomerRepo extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {
    @Query(
        value = "SELECT * FROM Customer c WHERE username = ':username' ORDER BY username ASC LIMIT 1",
        nativeQuery = true
    )
    public Customer findAllByUsername(@Param("username") String username );
```

Comment: Can you upload your example project?

Comment: @KedarJoshi you're right!

Comment: which, of course, is nothing to do with the JPA API, and everything to do with the "Spring Data JPA" API. Totally different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind parameters should not be wrapped inside quotes. Make sure to remove single quotes around  `:username`.

Correct query would be `SELECT * FROM Customer c WHERE username = :username ORDER BY username ASC LIMIT 1`